# Embeddable widget showing products from a e-shop API using JS slider

Tags: php, javascript, widget

I need to develop an embeddable widget which has to look something like this:

```
    <div id="my_widget" data-api_key="xxx" data-shop_id="xxx"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my_widget.js"></script>
```

The API Request must be in PHP implemented. I have to show the three more sold products for the shop by id `data-shop_id`.

I'm ok with the PHP coding, my problem is how to implement that my_widget.js and how to integrate it with a jQuery slider. And how do I use that data-api_key and data-shop_id labels in the PHP?

It would be OK to use `<iframe>` or is better pure JavaScript?

Sorry if it sounds a bit confuse, I'm still wondering how to do it. If you know some tutorial about how to implement a widget using PHP + JavaScript, I'd be pleased.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to use an iframe.

Although you could use jQuery to post the data-shop_id and then receive the results as JSON and process them.

jQuery access data attribute - $(this).data("shop_id")